# Spring SAML one time use condition

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-saml

I am trying to connect to a custom cas 4 implementation with spring security saml. Spring lib throws an exception because of the assertion condition is one time use. I commented it out extending the base class and I made it work. I wondering why there is such a limitation on the library.
Thanks for any help.
Being more specific in the method verifyAssertionConditions of the class class WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl there is this code:

```
else if (conditionQName.equals(OneTimeUse.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)) {
  throw new SAMLException("System cannot honor OneTimeUse condition of the Assertion for WebSSO");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring SAML uses the received `Assertion` throughout its validity period and cannot be forced to request a new one with possibly different values (e.g. access roles) - which is my understanding of the intention of `OneTimeUse` condition in this context (details are in [SAML 2 core](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf)). For that reason Spring SAML rejects SAML Responses which have this condition set.

You can change the behavior by overriding `verifyAssertionConditions` in `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl`, filtering the condition out and calling super with the remaining ones.

Comment: The reason why the Identity Provider has this OneTimeUse feature is to prevent Replay attack. It would be good if spring saml  implement it

Comment: This feature is typically implemented by using an anti-replay cache, I heard :)

Comment: I've always interpreted the OneTimeUse as above - where its intention seems to be not prevention of replay attacks (which is addressed by range of other mechanisms - like expiration of HTTP-Artifacts after resolution, mandated preventions of re-use of ResponseIDs in HTTP-POST, or lot of time-based expirations on messages), but instruction to expire the message right after use.

Comment: But after looking at few other products and re-reading the SAML 2.0 errata I have to admit that you are right and it should be treated as a replay-prevention mechanism in the context of WebSSO. The current behavior of Spring SAML is still correct, but your feature request is definitely valid. Opening it in Jira (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES/component/10711/) would be helpful.